# video player as ListView item of Android

Tags: android, listview, youtube, android-video-player

i want to show a video player in my ListView, and i tried with regular video player and surface View which is not worked

for more info [similar like  vine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.vine.android&hl=en)

Comment: use videoview to make it work easily.

Comment: I have a same problem too. VideoViews in ListView does not work.

Comment: Best way is to use TextureView to play video in listview